# Why does a static variable initialized by a method call that returns another static variable remains null?

Tags: java, static-variables

I simply don't understand the following code's execution flow:

```
class Test {
    static String s1 = getVal();
    static String s2 = "S2";

    private static String getVal() {
        return s2;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(s2); // prints S2
        System.out.println(s1); // prints null
    }
}
```

It is supposed to print `S2` at second `println` statement. I am more interested in understanding why this happens rather than a solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Static things gets executed in the order they appear in the code.

```
static String s1 = getVal();
```

So starting with first line, `s1` gets evaluated and by that time `s2` is still `null`. Hence you see the null value.

Answer (score 16):

`static` variables and `static` initializer blocks are initialized in the order they appear in the source code (except of `static final` variables that get initialized before non-final `static` variables).

`s1` is initialized before `s2`, therefore the call to `getVal()` returns the default value of `s2`, which is `null`.

You can change the order of the `static` variables in order to initialize `s2` first:

```
static String s2 = "S2";
static String s1 = getVal();
```

Another way to force the initialization of `s2` to take place before that of `s1` is to make `s2` final:

```
static String s1 = getVal();
static final String s2 = "S2";
```

Following is an excerpt of the initialization order as stated in [JLS 12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2). The sections related to `static` variables are highlighted.

> For each class or interface C, there is a unique initialization lock LC. The mapping from C to LC is left to the discretion of the Java Virtual Machine implementation. The procedure for initializing C is then as follows:
>
> 1. Synchronize on the initialization lock, LC, for C. This involves waiting until the current thread can acquire LC.
> 2. If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by some other thread, then release LC and block the current thread until informed that the in-progress initialization has completed, at which time repeat this step.
> 3. If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by the current thread, then this must be a recursive request for initialization. Release LC and complete normally.
> 4. If the Class object for C indicates that C has already been initialized, then no further action is required. Release LC and complete normally.
> 5. If the Class object for C is in an erroneous state, then initialization is not possible. Release LC and throw a NoClassDefFoundError.
> 6. Otherwise, record the fact that initialization of the Class object for C is in progress by the current thread, and release LC.
>
>    Then, **initialize the static fields of C which are constant variables**(§4.12.4, §8.3.2, §9.3.1).
> 7. Next, if C is a class rather than an interface, then let SC be its superclass and let SI1, ..., SIn be all superinterfaces of C that declare at least one default method. The order of superinterfaces is given by a recursive enumeration over the superinterface hierarchy of each interface directly implemented by C (in the left-to-right order of C's implements clause). For each interface I directly implemented by C, the enumeration recurs on I's superinterfaces (in the left-to-right order of I's extends clause) before returning I.
>
>    For each S in the list [ SC, SI1, ..., SIn ], if S has not yet been initialized, then recursively perform this entire procedure for S. If necessary, verify and prepare S first.
>
>    If the initialization of S completes abruptly because of a thrown exception, then acquire LC, label the Class object for C as erroneous, notify all waiting threads, release LC, and complete abruptly, throwing the same exception that resulted from initializing S.
> 8. Next, determine whether assertions are enabled (§14.10) for C by querying its defining class loader.
> 9. Next, **execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block**.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) section 12.4.2, the static fields are initialised like this:

> Next, execute either the **class variable initializers** and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in **textual order**, as though they were a single block.

So `s1` is initialised first, at which point `s2`  is not initialised, so it has the default value of `String`, which is `null`.

And then `s2` gets initialised to `"S2"` but `s1` stays `null`.

Just change the order of the two declarations to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**s1** is initialized first and the value of **s2** is null at that time.
**s1** is trying to return the value of **s2** which has been initialized later.
That's why you are getting it as null.

If you try like this you will get the expected answer 'S2'

```
class Test {

    static String s2 = "S2";
    static String s1 = getVal();
    private static String getVal() {
        return s2;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(s2); // prints S2
        System.out.println(s1); // prints S2
    }
}
```